# Highcharts/Stockcharts - display absolute value within 100%

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a graph with a percentage and an absolute value. I want to keep the max size of the graph at 100%. The issue I have with this is that the absolute value goes out of the graph. Is there a feature I couldn't find that allows me to set the max `playersOnline` value as 100% and calculate the rest accordingly to it? Or do you have another, better idea?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use stacking option? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.stacking

Comment: Stacking does something else, take a look at the example ;)

Comment: But it is only supported solution, other is calculate your data in the preprocessing then use in the highcharts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert absolute values of `playersOnline` to percentage values so that the maximum value of this chart was equal to 100%. But you need to show absolute values in the tooltip. To resolve it, you can use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter). In this callback function you can convert back percentage values of `playersOnline` to absolute values.